# NGINX causes index.php to be downloaded when an access list is applied

Tags: php, apache, nginx

I am trying to limit the access to a certain administration page.
I have however with the following config in my nginx.conf:

```
server {
    listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied

    root /var/www;
    server_name asdf;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://192.168.1.1:88/;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
    #location /server/administrator/ {
    #       allow 127.0.0.0/24;
    #       allow my.ip/32;
    #}
}
```

Everything works with this config, the requests are passed to my apache2 listening on port 88. However, when I remove the comments from my access restriction, my index.php is being downloaded instead of processed. Maybe someone has seen this before?

Comment: Could you please test, which directive gives you this problem? I suspect the `/32` to be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your administration page is on the 192.168.1.1 backend as well your location block needs to look like this

```
location /server/administrator/ {
    proxy_pass http://192.168.1.1:88;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    allow 127.0.0.0/24;
    allow my.ip/32;
    deny all;
}
```

You want to deny all except the two allowed, you need to tell nginx, where to proxy your request to in the specific location

EDIT:

If the administration page is on your nginx box and you want it to be executed you need to run fastcgi or php-fpm.
Unlike Apache, nginx doesn't offer php or other server-side scripting on its own, but it can talk to a fastcgi-like backend using fastcgi_pass instead of proxy_pass.

Check this out to get an idea about how to get nginx running with php-fpm

http://www.lifelinux.com/how-to-install-nginx-and-php-fpm-on-centos-6-via-yum/

Comment: Thanks, indeed the proxy_pass fixed my issues, however i had to specify the exact path in the pass - proxy_pass http://192.168.1.1:88//server/administrator/. Otherwise I was getting an index.html not found. In any case it worked. Thanks again.

Comment: @Involar you don't need to specify the exact path. You just need to remove `/` at the end of `proxy_pass http://192.168.1.1:88/` in this answer. Please, read the documentation: http://nginx.org/r/proxy_pass

Answer (score 1):

Your first location is being passed to Apache, but the second is processed by NginX, who does not know what PHP is, and therefore allows you to download it as a binary file.

You could simply setup access control in `server/administrator/index.php` by inspecting the `X-REAL-IP` header as supplied by NginX.

```
if ($_SERVER["HTTP_X_REAL_IP"] != 'my IP')
{
    if (false === strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_X_REAL_IP"], '127.0.0.'))
    {
        // 302 redirect to home
        Header("Location: http://yoursite/");
        die("Access denied");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
server {
    listen   80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.1:88;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

        location /server/administrator/ {
            allow 127.0.0.0/24;
            allow my.ip/32;
            proxy_pass http://192.168.1.1:88;
        }
    }
}
```

You forgot `proxy_pass` in your new location.

See:

- http://nginx.org/r/location
- http://nginx.org/r/proxy_pass